# How to figure out the correct name to include graphics?

Tags: includegraphics

I am having trouble using the `includegraphics` command. I assume it is because I gave the wrong name (my file contains space character and I got error messages because of it).

Also, where should I put the graphics so that I don't have to put the full path name. I assume it is the working directory? But how am I supposed to find where is my work directory (I am on a Mac)?

Comment: You can place an image file in the same directory that your .tex file is in. You can then include it using `\includegraphics{<my file name>}` replacing `<my file name>` with the name of the image file you want to include.

Comment: You may also do `\usepackage{graphicx}` then `\graphicspath{<path>}`, where `<path>` is the path to the directory holding all the documents graphics files, often a subdirectory of the directory holding the source `.tex` file.

Comment: With UNIX you can create links and with MSDOS you can create shortcuts to both locate and rename a file.  I'm sure Macs have somehting similar.  Aha, try alias.